# WebApi return JSON and put a '$' symbol as prefix in some properties?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to put '$' before some properties of my object returned by WebApi?

I have a class so far:

```
public class Customer 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public BagData BagData { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to return an instance of this class from my webapi controller as JSON (see '$' before BagData property):

```
{ Id:1, Name:"Alexandre Trindade", $BagData:"foo" }
```

BagData is just a kind of 'private property' I want to use in javascript. But I don't know how my webapi method can put $ before BagData property.

I know that I can return a string from my webapi and use JsonConvert to render my instance as json and after put '$' symbol in that property. But I don't like this, I want that my controller returns an object:

```
[HttpGet]
public Customer GetCustomer(int id)
{
    ....
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JsonProperty attribute.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$BagData")]
    public BagData BagData { get; set; }
}
```